# how to create a batch script that creates a text file and takes all the names of files in another folder and stores them in the original text file

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file

The instructions are as follows :
The script must create a file named files.txt and display its contents. The file must contain all the names (only) in the %windir%\system32 directory that meet the following conditions:
- the file name is 4 letters and its extension is .com (ex: mode.com) - the 2nd letter of the file name is "i" and its extension is .dll (ex: windows.dll)

I'm a beginner and the only thing I have right now is :
break>"C:\Users\username\Desktop\Folder\files.txt" (to create the text file)
I think i might have to do a loop with ''for'' for the conditions i'm not too sure

Comment: This may seem like a nit-pick, but I feel that it isn’t.  What does “names (only)” mean?  Does it mean only the filenames and not meta-data like file size and modification date/time?  Or does it mean only the ***base*** names, excluding the extensions (so it should show ``mode`` and ``windows`` rather than ``mode.com`` and ``windows.dll``)?

Comment: This appears to be a homework question

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve these things by using the dir command and by using wildcards.
There are two wildcards that you can use to achieve these patterns.
First we have the * wildcard this one will match any sequence of characters.
And we also have the ? this wildcard matches only one character.

Now if you want to output the command to a file you can either use > or >>.
The difference is that >> will append an existing file but when you use > the file will only contain the output of the command. The file will in both cases be created if it does not exist.

Here is an example if we want to list all files where the second letter is an i and the extension is .dll. I use the /b parameter to only list the files and not display the other information that dir usually shows. I place the output on the desktop.

```
cd %windir%\system32
dir ?i*.dll /b >> %userprofile%\desktop\files.txt
```

I'm not going to write the whole script for you. You should be able to write the script on your own with this information.

Answer (score 0):

*** See Paste Link For Updated Code ***

Voilà. Happy New Years.
Not bad for only having started learning batch 3 months ago, with no other coding experience of note.

I must ask though, what is the point? what's the usefulness of sorting the data so?

*** Updated to include detailed remarks ***

```
@ECHO OFF

REM - Required to access variables used during for loops:
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

REM - Remove Old Log if Exists
IF exist "files.txt" (
DEL /Q "files.txt"
)

REM - Variable used to Establish the Array:
Set Val=0

REM - Not strictly necessary, A variable used for the PATH to be Processed.
Set Home_Dir=%windir%\system32

REM - Assign Extensions For processing and call Function.
Set "ext=com" && CALL :process
Set "ext=dll" && CALL :process

REM - Opens the Results of Processing for review.
Start notepad.exe files.txt

REM - For /R Loop Searches the Directory for Files matching the extension
REM - %%~na expands to the name of %%a.
REM - %%~xa expands to the extension of %%a.
REM - %%~dpa expands to the directory %%a is in (drive letter and path).
REM - Note: Only the Filename has been stored in this script.
REM - If you wish to store the whole path, change the >> store to:
REM - !filepath[%val%]!!name[%val%]!!EXT[%val%]! >>files.txt

REM - The below is a recursive Option. OP did not state explicitely if Subfolders needed or Not.
REM - If Recursive Option Is NOT needed, Refer to the Linked paste for the Method
REM - Of Setting the Array For CD files Only.
:process
FOR /R "%Home_Dir%" %%a IN (*.%ext%) DO (
    Set name[!val!]=%%~na
    Set EXT[!val!]=%%~xa
    Set filepath[!val!]=%%~dpa
    Set /a Val+=1
    CALL :extFilter
)
GOTO :EOF

:extFilter
ECHO !name[%val%]!

REM - Call sub function to test .com filelength
IF "!EXT[%val%]!"==".com" CALL :Filter_com

REM - Call sub function to test 2nd letter in .dll filename
IF "!EXT[%val%]!"==".dll" CALL :Filter_dll
GOTO :EOF

:Filter_dll
Set "testletter=!name[%val%]!"

REM - Breaks the string down ~offsetFromStringLeft,HowManyCharactersToUse%
Set testletter=%testletter:~1,1%

REM - Test the Isolated letter against the desired Value and Store if true.
IF /I "!testletter!"=="i" ECHO !name[%val%]! >>files.txt
GOTO :EOF

:Filter_com

REM - Call Function to determine the String's Length.
Call :strlen result !name[%val%]!

REM - Test if String Length of Name Matches Desired Value and Store if true.
IF !result!==4 ECHO !name[%val%]! >>files.txt
GOTO :EOF

REM - strlen - Function that progressively tests String length using a temporary
REM - string to offset the string length by %%P, then Comparing the result
REM - of the offset to see if the string is empty.
REM - Once the Offset returns an empty string, the cumulative value of %%P
REM - becomes the Stringlength (%len%), and the value is returned as result.

:strlen <resultVar> <stringVar>
set tmp=%~2
If defined tmp (
        set "len=1"
        for %%P in (4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1) do (
            if "!tmp:~%%P,1!" NEQ "" ( 
                set /a "len+=%%P"
                set "tmp=!tmp:~%%P!"
            )
        )
    ) ELSE (
        set len=0
)
( 
    set "%~1=%len%"
    exit /b
)
```

***** Strlen function from [How do you get the string length
in a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5837418/3960947#5841587) By [Jeb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/463115/jeb) *****
Paste can be found: [Here](https://pastebin.com/VBswTFsZ)

Comment: Please try to lower your code-to-explanation ratio (i.e., for that much code, provide much much more explanation).

Comment: Answer edited to include Remarks in the function regarding what the code is doing and how.

Comment: (1) OK, that’s an improvement.  (2) What’s the point? … … … … … … It’s obviously homework.  (3) I don’t see anything in the question that suggests that a recursive search of the directory is requested.  (4) This writes the names of the DLL files to `files.txt` twice, because it should (but doesn’t) exit after the `start notepad` statement on line 17.  (5) Line 38 writes the name of every file the script processes to the standard output.  I assume that this is a debug statement that you meant to delete before you posted your code. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (6) Is there any reason to save the filenames in arrays?  As far as I can see, you take each name, test it, and either write it to the file or don’t — you never go back and look at them again.  So using arrays just complicates the code.  (6b) Line 6 says “REM - Variable used to Establish the Array:”.  That’s the *only* remark that says anything about arrays — that’s sad.  (7) It doesn’t matter — but you could use `%testletter%` (instead of `!testletter!`) on line 54, and `%result%` (instead of `!result!`) on line 63.

Comment: EXIT point Corrected, Had already been revised in Linked Code.

I'm In the Habit of !expanding variables! when in for Loops, results in less issues.

As for the reason behind storing them into Arrays, you're correct in the fact it's not required, However, I can't help but to write code thats easily built upon or modified for other purposes. It's a minor deviation that makes the code repurposable- however didn't detail Arrays because that's not the question.

You missed the really obvious nitpick though... I had no cleanup of the Log file prior to running...